# Using dynamic parameters value in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use a dynamic parameter in PowerShell, but the value for the parameter doesn't seem to exist after I have run through my script.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter(
         Mandatory=$true,
         Position=0,
         HelpMessage = "The entity ID for the Version"
    )]
    [string]$TPVersionID,

    [Parameter(
         Mandatory=$true,
         Position=1,
         HelpMessage = ""
    )]
    [string]$VersionNumber,

    [Parameter(
         Mandatory=$true,
         Position=2,
         HelpMessage = "This is a boolean value; enter any value to make it True, leave it blank to make it False."
    )]
    [bool]$PullVersionDoc
)


function Get-VersionParam{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param ([string]$TPVersionID, [string]$VersionNumber, [bool]$PullVersionDoc?)
    DynamicParam {
        if ($PullVersionDoc) {
            write-host("HEY!")

            $attributes = new-object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
            $attributes.Position = 3
            $attributes.Mandatory = $true
            $attributeCollection = new-object `
                -Type System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
            $attributeCollection.Add($attributes)

            $dynParam1 = new-object `
                -Type System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter('VersionDocumentID', [Int32], $attributeCollection)

            $paramDictionary = new-object `
                -Type System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
            $paramDictionary.Add('VersionDocumentID', $dynParam1)
            return $paramDictionary
        }
    }
}


Get-VersionParam


#Write-Host "Dynamic Parameter PullVersionDoc? = " $PullVersionDoc
Write-Host $PSBoundParameters
```

I want the script to ask for a [VersionDocumentID] if the boolean value for [PullVersionDoc] is TRUE to use later on in the script, but when I write out the [$PSBoundParameters] the parameter doesn't exist. How did I get the value so that I can use it?

Comment: `$a = Get-VersionParam; Write-host $a`

Comment: There's also no point in using a `[bool]` parameter. Use `[switch]` instead. This way you add the param name to make Switch True or leave it off and it will evaluate to False.  Also, you access `$PSBoundParameters[$ParameterName]` in the Begin block and work on items within the Process block.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The `VersionDocumentID` parameter will only exist inside the function, unless you add something like `$script:VersionDocumentID = $VersionDocumentID` to your function body (or outputs the value and store it like @4c74356b41 showed) . Your function doesn't do anything except ask for values it never uses.

Comment: I agree with @FrodeF. which prompted me to post my complete Dynamic Param example script in the hopes it will assist the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I tried using dynamic parameters to get Configuration Manager logs.

Credit goes to the [blog post here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pstips/2014/06/09/dynamic-validateset-in-a-dynamic-parameter/).

Usage: `Get-CCMLogs -ComputerNames -Remote -RemoteLogName <Tab to complete lognames>`

Local usage: `Get-CCMLogs -ComputerNames -LocalLogName <Tab to complete lognames>`

The dynamic parameter will return a remote log name if the switch `-Remote` is entered or return a local log name if the switch `-Remote` is not entered.

```
Function Get-CCMLogs {

    [CmdletBinding()]

    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
            HelpMessage="Give me a list of computer names!")]
        [Alias('Hostname','cn')]
        [string[]]$ComputerNames = $env:COMPUTERNAME,

        [switch]$Remote
    )

    DynamicParam{

        If ($Remote) {

            $ParameterName = 'RemoteLogName'

            $RunTimeDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary

            $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]

            $ParamAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
            $ParamAttribute.Mandatory = $true
            $ParamAttribute.Position = 1

            $AttributeCollection.Add($ParamAttribute)

            $ValidateItems = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$ComputerNames\C$\Windows\CCM\Logs" | Where {$_ -notmatch '\d+'} | Select -ExpandProperty FullName
            $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($ValidateItems)

            $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)

            $RunTimeParam = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ParameterName, [string], $AttributeCollection)

            $RunTimeDictionary.Add($ParameterName, $RunTimeParam)

            Return $RunTimeDictionary
        }
        else {
            $ParameterName = 'LocalLogName'

            $RunTimeDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary

            $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]

            $ParamAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
            $ParamAttribute.Mandatory = $true
            $ParamAttribute.Position = 1

            $AttributeCollection.Add($ParamAttribute)

            $ValidateItems = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Windows\CCM\Logs | Select -ExpandProperty FullName | Where {$_ -notmatch '\d+'}
            $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($ValidateItems)

            $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)

            $RunTimeParam = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ParameterName, [string], $AttributeCollection)

            $RunTimeDictionary.Add($ParameterName, $RunTimeParam)

            Return $RunTimeDictionary
        }
    }

    Begin{
        $LogName = $PSBoundParameters[$ParameterName]
    }

    Process{
        cmtrace.exe $LogName
    }
}
```