# Trying to verify remote command passed was successful in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, command, skype

I am still researching the best way to do this. If anyone has a suggestion please let me know.

1. I am looking to pass PowerShell commands to a remote machine and receive verification that the command was successful.
2. The script should not proceed until result is received.
3. If command fails it should attempt again until it is successful on the remote computer, failure may occur if AD and Skype replication has not completed.

Here is what I have so far.

Not quite working but the above 3 rules. If there is a better way of doing this I am all ears.

```
        $SkypeFeRemoteComputers = Get-SkypeRegistrarPoolInfo -Pool $RegistrarPool
        $RemoteFEComputerCompletedSuccessfull = $false

        foreach ($Computer in $SkypeFeRemoteComputers) {
            if ($RemoteFEComputerCompletedSuccessfull -eq $false) {
                try {
                    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -AsJob -JobName myJob_NewCommonAreaPhone -ErrorAction Stop -ArgumentList $LineURI,$RegistrarPool, $OU_CommonArea, $Description, $DisplayName, $DisplayNumber, $SIP -ScriptBlock {
                        Param($R_LineURI, $R_RegistrarPool, $R_OU_CommonArea, $R_Description, $R_DisplayName, $R_DisplayNumber, $R_SIP)

                        New-CsCommonAreaPhone -LineUri $R_LineURI -RegistrarPool $R_RegistrarPool -OU $R_OU_CommonArea -Description $R_Description -DisplayName $R_DisplayName -DisplayNumber $R_DisplayNumber -SipAddress $R_SIP -WhatIf;
                        Move-CsCommonAreaPhone -Identity $R_SIP -Target $R_RegistrarPool;
                        Grant-CsClientPolicy -PolicyName "SkypeUI" -Identity $R_SIP;
                        Grant-CsVoicePolicy -PolicyName "NA-TX-LAP" -Identity $R_SIP;
                        Grant-CsDialPlan -PolicyName "NA-TX-LAP" -Identity $R_SIP;
                        Set-CsClientPin -Identity $R_SIP -Pin 1111;
                    }
                    Get-Job
                    $Result = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
                        Receive-Job -Name myJob_NewCommonAreaPhone -Keep
                    }
                    if ($Result -eq $true) {
                        $RemoteFEComputerCompletedSuccessfull = $true
                    }
                } catch {
                    Add-Content Unavailable-Computers.txt $Computer
                }
            }
        }
        Write-Host "New-CsCommonAreaPhone -LineUri $lineuri -RegistrarPool $SFBFQDNRegistrarPool -OU $OU -Description $Description -DisplayName $DisplayName -DisplayNumber $DisplayNumber -SipAddress $SIP"
    } else {
        Write-Host "Set-CsCommonAreaPhone -identity $sip -sipaddress $sip -DisplayName $phone.Display -DisplayNumber $phone.Display"
    }
}
```

Somethings I am researching to do this is perhaps also `Invoke-Expression`.

Comment: A few things don't look right with your code.  For example, you invoke the command using `-ComputerName`, then try to connect later with a session object, `$session`, which doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.  You create a job object on your local computer, but try to retrieve it on a different one.  The `-WhatIf` parameter will make the cmdlet tell you what it _would_ do without actually doing the work, so it will never be successful.  What do you define as successful?  How you determine that will help you decide how to approach the problem (use Jobs or not, etc).

Comment: Here Simplistically what  I would like to do.

Comment: Here Simplistically what  I would like to do.

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -AsJob -JobName myJob_NewCommonAreaPhone -ErrorAction Stop -ArgumentList $LineURI,$RegistrarPool, $OU_CommonArea, $Description, $DisplayName, $DisplayNumber, $SIP -ScriptBlock {
                        Param($R_LineURI, $R_RegistrarPool, $R_OU_CommonArea, $R_Description, $R_DisplayName, $R_DisplayNumber, $R_SIP)

Comment: New-CsCommonAreaPhone -LineUri $R_LineURI -RegistrarPool $R_RegistrarPool -OU $R_OU_CommonArea -Description $R_Description -DisplayName $R_DisplayName -DisplayNumber $R_DisplayNumber -SipAddress $R_SIP -WhatIf;
                       }`

I know I can make this work with the -cred parameter.

what I want is for the command to return True if the command completed successfully and false if it failed.

Comment: My whole reason for this is when the command ( Set-CsClientPin -Identity $R_SIP -Pin 1111) the command will fail if AD and Skype have not completed the replication.   So I am looking a way to catch this failure, and rerun it until it passes.

Comment: All these commands must be ran on a remote machine from the source machine

Comment: Successful means the remote machine that ran the command did not produce any error (red text)
And can produce the successful info if available.

Comment: on and I do not want the script to continue until the command invoked was successful

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet found a solution to validate the script sent ran successfully or not. However the next best item I could come up with was to test that WinRM I could communicate and would accept commands. Then  I guess I have to just trust WinRM completed the Invoke Command.

```html
Function Enable-CommonAreaPhones
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        #[Parameter(Position = 2)]
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] 
        $DisplayName, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] 
        $SIP, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] 
        $LineURI, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] 
        $OU_CommonArea, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] 
        $CreateNewCAP = $true,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] 
        $RegistrarPool, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] 
        $DisplayNumber,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] 
        $Description
    )
    <#
    dynamicparam {
        #https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/10/06/implement-dynamic-parameters.aspx
        #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318419/powershell-using-dynamic-parameters-value
        #https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3704
        $ParameterName_SFBRegistrarPool = 'SFBRegistrarPool'
        $ParamAttrib = New-Object  System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParamAttrib.Mandatory = $true
        $ParamAttrib.ParameterSetName = '__AllParameterSets'
        
        $AttribColl = New-Object  System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        $AttribColl.Add($ParamAttrib)
            $ValidateItems = (get-csservice -Registrar).PoolFqdn
            
            $AttribColl.Add((New-Object  System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($ValidateItems)))

        $RuntimeParam = New-Object  System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ParameterName_SFBRegistrarPool, [string],  $AttribColl)

        $RuntimeParamDic = New-Object  System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
        $RuntimeParamDic.Add($ParameterName_SFBRegistrarPool, $RuntimeParam)

        return $RuntimeParamDic
    }
        begin
        {$RegistrarPool = $PsBoundParameters[$ParameterName_SFBRegistrarPool]}
        process
        {}
        End
        {}
    #>

    if ($CreateNewCAP)
    {
        <#
        #$Description = "Huddle-N405-172B"
        #$DisplayName = "(713)577-3160"
        #$DisplayNumber = "+1-713-577-3160"
        #$LineURI = 'tel:+17135773160;ext=3160'
        #$SIP = 'sip:Huddle-N405-172B.BR172B@mrcglobal.com'
        #$OU = "OU=172B LA PORTE -- TX,OU=Gulf Coast,OU=CAP,OU=Lync,DC=mcjunkinredman,DC=com"
        #$RegistrarPool = 'hexlsfepool.mcjunkinredman.com'
        #>

        param($LineURI,$RegistrarPool, $OU_CommonArea, $Description, $DisplayName, $DisplayNumber,$SIP )
        write-host "New-CsCommonAreaPhone -LineUri $lineuri -RegistrarPool $SFBFQDNRegistrarPool -OU $OU -Description $Description -DisplayName $DisplayName -DisplayNumber $DisplayNumber -SipAddress $SIP"
        
        New-CsCommonAreaPhone -LineUri $LineURI -RegistrarPool $RegistrarPool -OU $OU_CommonArea -Description $Description -DisplayName $DisplayName -DisplayNumber $DisplayNumber -SipAddress $SIP -WhatIf;
        Grant-CsClientPolicy -PolicyName "SkypeUI" -Identity $SIP;
        Grant-CsVoicePolicy -PolicyName "NA-TX-LAP" -Identity $SIP;
        Grant-CsDialPlan -PolicyName "NA-TX-LAP" -Identity $SIP;
        #Set-CsClientPin –Identity $SIP -Pin 1111;
        #Move-CsCommonAreaPhone -Identity $SIP -Target $R_RegistrarPool; 
    }
    Else
    {
        #Get-CsCommonAreaPhone | Set-CsCommonAreaPhone -Enabled $True
        #Get-CsCommonAreaPhone -Filter {Description -eq $Null} | Set-CsCommonAreaPhone -Description "Common area phone"
        #Get-CsCommonAreaPhone -Filter {LineUri -eq "tel:+14255556710"} | Set-CsCommonAreaPhone -DisplayName "Employee Lounge"

    }
}

function invoke-SkypeObject_RemoteModification_CommonAreaPhones
{
    #Finds all Front End Servers
    $SkypeFeRemoteComputers = Get-SkypeRegistrarPoolInfo -Pool $RegistrarPool 
    $RemoteFEComputerCompletedSuccessfull = $false

    ForEach ($Computer in $SkypeFeRemoteComputers)
    {
        #Validates Command has only ran on 1 machine
        #Validates the computer exists and can accept invoke commands via the WinRM Command
        If ((!($RemoteFEComputerCompletedSuccessfull)) -and (Test-Connection -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -Quiet) -and (Test-WSMan -ComputerName $computer -ErrorAction Ignore))
        {
            #https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-functions.html
            $scriptblock = $executioncontext.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock(${function:Enable-CommonAreaPhones})
            Invoke-Command -Session $allsession -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -ArgumentList $R_LineURI,$R_RegistrarPool, $R_OU_CommonArea, $R_Description, $R_DisplayName, $R_DisplayNumber,$R_SIP -ErrorVariable errorMsg
            Invoke-Command -Session $allsession -ScriptBlock ${function:Enable-CommonAreaPhones} -ArgumentList $R_LineURI,$R_RegistrarPool, $R_OU_CommonArea, $R_Description, $R_DisplayName, $R_DisplayNumber,$R_SIP -ErrorVariable errorMsg
            $RemoteFEComputerCompletedSuccessfull = $true
        }   
    }

}
```