# How to set param as mandatory if choice selected from set

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

I have the following parameter input and three choices the user can type:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateSet('View','Add','Remove')]
    [String]$Command,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [String]$UserID
)
```

How can I make it so that it's mandatory to enter `$UserID` if `$Command` is either "Add" or "Remove", while not mandatory if "View" is the command?

Comment: Make distinct parameter sets instead of using one parameter `$Command`. Otherwise you'll have to use dynamic parameters.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers i am fine with dynamic params. how do i accomplish that?

Comment: I haven't used dynamic parameters myself, but maybe [this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42318419/1630171). My recommendation is: use distinct (static) parameter sets.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers ok, suppose i made $View, $Add, and $Remove parameters. how can i say if $Add/$Remove, then set $UserID to mandatory?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers quick question; so currently the $userID takes one value as input. is it possible to make it take in a string of comma separated values, so as to allow for adding/removing multipl ID's at once instead of having to run the script for each ID?

Comment: If you pass a comma-separated string you need to split that string yourself inside the function. You can make the parameter accept an array of strings, though: `[String[]]$UserID`. Then you could pass the values like this: `test.ps1 -Add -UserID 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'`. This won't work if you intend to run the script from outside PowerShell (e.g. from CMD), because PowerShell arrays aren't recognized there.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers ah! Interesting. I do use batch file to run powershell script with execution policy in CMD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICS you need dynamic parameters for what you're asking (see for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42318419/1630171)). Personally, I'd recommend using distinct (static) parameter sets, though:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='View')]
Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Add', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Switch]$Add,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Remove', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Switch]$Remove,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='View', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Switch]$View,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Add', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Remove', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='View', Mandatory=$false)]
    [String]$UserID
)

switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
    'Add'    { ... }
    'Remove' { ... }
    'View'   { ... }
}
```

Usage:

```
PS C:\> test.ps1 -?
test.ps1 -View [-UserID ] []
test.ps1 -Add -UserID  []
test.ps1 -Remove -UserID  []
```

Comment: suppose i have if statements based on the parameter...would it be if($Add) elseif($Remove) else ? since i set $command to [string] i am able to use it such as if ($Command -eq 'Add') , but i am not sure how i can make conditional with [switch]

Comment: @Cataster You mean how to identify the parameter set that was used inside the function? See updated answer.

Comment: excellent. i just implemented this in my script. it works wonders :D